# Error while moving on to other page in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Currently am writing a full stack website, which uses Nodejs and Mongodb for Backend and reactjs for Frontend. I am having a problem in react. As I am new to developing, my explanation of the problem won't be accurate, forgive me for this.
Coming to the error, when am at my home page, it gets every picture and all the stuff perfectly, but when I go to profile page, the pictures wont get updated and they wont appear. I don't know why, please help me....
This is my feed page

```js
import "./feed.css";
import Post from "../post/Post";
import Share from "../share/Share";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Feed({username}) {
  const [posts,setPosts]=useState([]);
  const [texts,setTexts]=useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchPosts=async ()=>{
      const res=username? 
      await axios.get("posts/profile/"+username):
      await axios.get("posts/timeline/63c29c2fe9a410383d4bcb98");
      setPosts(res.data);
    };
    fetchPosts(); 
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <div className="feedWrapper">
        
        <Share/>
        {posts.map((p)=>(
          <Post key={p._id} post={p}/>
        
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is my Profile.jsx

```js
import "./profile.css"
import Topbar from "../../components/topbar/Topbar";
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import Feed from "../../components/feed/Feed";
import Rightbar from "../../components/rightbar/Rightbar";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function Profile() {
  const [user,setUser]= useState({});
  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchUser=async ()=>{
      const res=await axios.get(`/users/?username=Bannu`);
      setUser(res.data);
    };
    fetchUser(); 
  },[]);
  return (
    <>
        <Topbar/>
        <div className="profile">
        <Sidebar/>
        <div className="profileRight">
          <div className="profileRightTop">
            <div className="profileCover">
            <img className="profileCoverImg" src={user.coverPicture||"assets/person/noCover.jpeg"} alt="" />
            <img className="profileUserImg"src="assets/person/7.jpeg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="profileInfo">
              <h4 className="profileInfoName">{user.username}</h4>
              <span className="profileInfoDesc">{user.desc}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="profileRightBottom">
        <Feed username='Bannu'/>
        <Rightbar user={user}/>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        </>
  )
}
```

This is Post.jsx

```js
import "./post.css";
import { MoreVert } from "@material-ui/icons";
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import {format} from 'timeago.js';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Post(post) {

    const [like,setLike]=useState(post.post.likes.length);
    const [isLiked,setIsLiked]=useState(false);
    const [user,setUser]=useState({});
    const likeHandler=()=>{
        setLike(isLiked?like-1:like+1);
        setIsLiked(!isLiked);
    };
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchUser=async ()=>{
          const res=await axios.get(`/users?userId=${post.post.userId}`);
          setUser(res.data);
        };
        fetchUser(); 
      },[post.post.userId]);
    
  return (
    <div className="post">
        <div className="postWrapper">
            <div className="postTop">
                <div className="postTopLeft">
                    <Link to={`profile/${user.username}`}>
                    <img className="postProfileImg"src={user.profilePicture||"assets/person/noAvatar.jpeg"} alt="" />
                    </Link>
                   
                  
                <span className="postUsername">{user.username}</span>
                <span className="postDate">{format(post.post.createdAt)}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="postTopRight">
                    <MoreVert/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="postCenter">
                <span className="postText">{post?.desc}</span>
                <img className="postImg" src={post.post.img} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="postBottom">
                <div className="postBottomLeft">
                    <img className="likeIcon" src="assets/like.png" onClick={likeHandler} alt="" />
                    <img className="likeIcon"src="assets/heart.jpeg" onClick={likeHandler} alt="" />
                <span className="postLikeCounter">{like} people like it</span>
                </div>
                <div className="postBottomRight">
                    <span className="postCommentText">{post.comment} comments</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is share.jsx

```js
import "./share.css"
import {PermMedia,Label, Room, EmojiEmotions} from '@material-ui/icons'
export default function Share() {
    return (
        <div className="share">
            <div className="shareWrapper">
                <div className="shareTop">
                    <img className="shareProfileImg" src="assets/person/1.png" alt="" />
                    <input type="text"
                        placeholder="What's in your mind?"
                        className="shareInput"
                    />
                </div>
                <hr className="shareHr" />
                <div className="shareBottom">
                    <div className="shareOptions">
                        <div className="shareOption">
                            <PermMedia htmlColor="tomato" className="shareIcon"/>
                            <span className="shareOptionText">Photo or Video</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="shareOption">
                            <Label htmlColor="blue"className="shareIcon"/>
                            <span className="shareOptionText">Tag</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="shareOption">
                            <Room htmlColor="green" className="shareIcon"/>
                            <span className="shareOptionText">Location</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="shareOption">
                            <EmojiEmotions htmlColor="goldenrod" className="shareIcon"/>
                            <span className="shareOptionText">Feeling</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button className="shareButton">Share</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

And these are the pictures of home and particular profile pages [Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnVL0.png)  [Particular profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ay9h.png). You can observe that in the profile page the image of a post is missing.
Help me ....

Comment: it will render before the useEffect , so put optional chaining in the src like user?.coverPicture

Comment: You probably don't want `jquery` as a tag.

Comment: No sir @SarthakGupta, Its isnt working.

Comment: assets/person/noAvatar.jpeg  , is it a valid path , can you just remove this and just keep that code with optional chaining and make sure you are getting that image in the api response

Comment: yes, its a valid path and am getting that image in the API response